# How to fix local port of sending UDP socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm developing an application using the Python socket module for sending packets with UDP. Due to regulation constraints, I need to restrict the local port of the socket too a range. I have tried:

```
def bind_to_port_range(low, high):
    m_counter = int(low)
    m_high = int(high)
    m_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    while m_counter <= m_high:
        try:
            m_socket.bind(("localhost", m_counter))
            return m_socket
        except:
            m_counter += 1
    return None

sock  = bind_to_port_range(6000, 6050)
if sock:
    sock.sendto(my_message, (destination_ip, destination_port))
```

Using netstat, I can see that the port is getting bound correctly, but the packet is not getting sent to the right destination. I am confident that the rest of my code is correct, as I not restricting the port to a range, and it was working just fine

```
# sock = bind_to_port_range(6000, 6050)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Is there something that I am missing here? Is there a way to restrict the sending sockets port range using UDP in this way? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the constraints. There is no security benefit and they lead to unimplementable applications.

Comment: If this was a constraint that was just because of how I want to implement it, then I would. However, one of the regulating bodies that monitor our company require us to keep documented all 'listening' ports, and our method of detecting these catches all open UDP ports as well, as they might be listening. Which means, that if I remove the constraint, we have accepted that python.exe can be listening on any port that could be automatically assigned, which my superiors don't want.

Comment: So your method of catching these is wrong. UDP ports do not listen. They send and receive. Only TCP ports listen. UDP ports should be excluded from your test completely.

Comment: You are correct. I should have said "require us to keep documented all ports that could receive a packet" and while for TCP we rely on looking at 'Listening' and 'Established' ports, there is no differentiation for UDP ports, and as such we must assume that all UDP ports could receive a packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was replace "localhost" with "".